# Unable to get Jupyter working with Apache Reverse Proxy for my Domain

Tags: apache, proxy, jupyter

I have the following entry in "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled" on my Ubuntu 15.10

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName "jupyter.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.254.23:8888/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.254.23:8888/
        Header edit Origin "jupyter.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com" 192.168.254.23:8888
        RequestHeader edit Origin "jupyter.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com" 192.168.254.23:8888

        Header edit Referer "jupyter.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com" 192.168.254.23:8888
        RequestHeader edit Referer "jupyter.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com" 192.168.254.23:8888
        <Location ~ "/(user/[^/]*)/(api/kernels/[^/]+/channels|terminals/websocket)/?">
                ProxyPass ws://192.168.254.23:8888/
                ProxyPassReverse ws://192.168.254.23:8888/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

After making the above entry I restarted apache: "sudo service apache2 restart"

When I attempt to run my script the Kernel is unable to connect.
[image: jupyterreverseproxy]

Console Logs:
[image: jupyterlogs]

The same works when I specify the IP Address though:
[image: jupyterwithipaddressandport]

Here's more info on my setup:

- Apache is running on Server A (Ubuntu 15.4, IP: 192.168.254.201)
- Jupyter installed on Server B (Centos 7, IP 192.168.254.23) as a
  Docker Image
  (https://www.dataquest.io/blog/data-science-quickstart-with-docker/)

And, I'm testing this from inside my home network, so no need to worry about proxy or ISP. I have the following entry in /etc/hosts

```
192.168.254.201 jupyter.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
```